# A question to Finite Multiplicative subgroups in a division ring of I. N. Herstein

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, division-algebras, division-ring

In [this](https://msp.org/pjm/1953/3-1/pjm-v3-n1-p08-p.pdf), I can't find the results in German as proof steps of Lemma 3 (... by Satz 88 [2, p. 72]) and Theorem 7 in page 123 (... Using results about division subalgebras of division algebras [1, p. 42, Satz 3] ... ).  Can you tell me about these? How his results have been extended to now? Has the hope at the end of your article been fulfilled?

Comment: The first one is about $p$-groups in which all proper subgroups are cyclic. See [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_p-groups_with_cyclic_maximal_subgroup) for classification of finite $p$-groups with a maximal cyclic subgroup.

Comment: Thank you so much @DerekHolt. You know the result about division subalgebras of division algebras [1, p. 42, Satz 3] , don't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 1955, S. A. Amitsur completely classified what types of finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of a division ring exist.

> S. A. Amitsur: Finite subgroups of division rings, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 80(1955), 361- 386. MR 17:577c

In this paper, he disproves Herstein’s conjecture.

A nice exposition by Lam exists which I will also recommend

> Lam, T. "Finite groups embeddable in division rings." Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 129.11 (2001): 3161-3166.

Comment: As of today, both papers were available openly by the publishers: [Amitsur's paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-080-02/S0002-9947-1955-0074393-9/S0002-9947-1955-0074393-9.pdf), [Lam's paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-11/S0002-9939-01-05961-5/S0002-9939-01-05961-5.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You know the result about division subalgebras of division algebras [1, p. 42, Satz 3] , don't you?

Comment: @TrầnNamSơn no, I’m only passingly familiar with these results through past interest .